# Javafx: new UI thread

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

```
...
public ProgressBar loadProgressBar;
...
Task task = new Task<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        {
            Platform.runLater(()
                    -> 
                    {

                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        Group root = new Group();
                        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 2000, 2000, Color.BLACK);
                        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Scene Graph Demo");
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.setMaximized(true);
                        //  stage.show();

                        Label tempLbl = new Label();
                        double h=0;
                        root.getChildren().add(tempLbl);
                        tempLbl.setText("");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
                        {
                            tempLbl.setText(tempLbl.getText()+"asd");
                            root.applyCss();
                            root.layout();
                            w=w+tempLbl.getHeight();
                            updateProgress(i, 10000000);
                        }
            });
            return null;
        }

    };

    loadProgressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
```

If you remove Platform.runLater tempLbl.getHeight () is always equal to 0.
If you leave the Platform.runLater loadProgressBar not updated until it reaches 100%.
How to avoid it?

Comment: Can you at least explain what you think this code is supposed to do?

Comment: This is a simplified version. The full version of the text is taken, paginated according to the font, height and length. Each time the page turn out different, depending on the settings. The code simply has to take and count it. But without braking the second stream or as I did not get to do it.

Comment: I understand this is probably just supposed to be a sample, but the code makes absolutely no sense at all. Why create something to run on a background thread that merely turns around and executes the whole thing back on the FX Application Thread?

Comment: If the code is not running in the UI thread, the height tempLbl remains equal to 0. The code does not work.

Comment: I don't even know what "work" means when the code makes so little sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well : :

1) Using `JavaFX Service` is recommended.

2) When you are trying to modify JavaFX Scene from external Thread you must use `Platform.runLater(..)`

3) If you want to see the progress changing add a `Thread.sleep(50)` for example inside the loop . Without sleep you will only see the progress when it reaches 100%

4) Some of `Task<?>` methods are allowed to be called from external Thread and some not . Them who are allowed to , if you see the internal code they are calling `Platform.isJavaFXThread()` and if not then they use `Platform.runLater();`

Comment: @Artyom I also reccomend you the book `Metro 2033` as you have the same name with the base actor .